# A man is about to kiss his girlfriend in a crowd. Is it correct for the girl to say "Stop it. We have eyes on us."?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

In the movie "**Stillwater**", a woman is about to kiss a man then the man says “**we got eyes on us.**” when he sees a little girl looking at them. ([see the movie script](https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/movies/stillwater-2021-transcript/))

And the man is American.

Does “**we got eyes on us.**” mean "**someone is watching us**"?

I think that action is happening right at that moment, so we should say "**we've got eyes on us.**" or "**we have eyes on us**".

A man is about to kiss his girlfriend in a crowd. Is it correct for the girl to say to the man "**Stop it. We have eyes on us.**"?

**Is it common to say that?**

Comment: It's impossible to say that something like that is 'correct' or 'incorrect'. As a British English speaker I would find it more natural to say 'There's someone looking' or 'People are watching'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While "we got eyes..." is not precisely grammatical, it is still a natural English construction, likely derived from a military context.  In military communication, communication shorthand is frequently used, and over the radio you might not be able to hear the difference between "we" and "we've" anyway, so the "'ve" gets dropped.  This has been heard often enough in movies, that it has entered the common language, but generally still retaining the military "feel".  When writing this phrase, you'll still usually write "...we've got...", but when speaking (or in a script) the "'ve" gets dropped.

Compare with "we got hostiles".  Again, this is not grammatical in proper formal English, but it is still used in military movies (and probably in the real military as well, but I don't have personal experience of that).  "We got eyes on us" sounds like the sort of thing a secret agent or spy would say to another spy.  Between a romantic couple, because of the "spy" association, this phrase would sound playful, possibly teasing.  It would generally not be used in an actual chiding or scolding manner, so "Stop it. We have eyes on us" sounds very strange to me, for the combination of the angry "stop it" and the playful spy-speak.

Comment: She said "stop it" to the man, not to the child. Does "Stop it. We have eyes on us" still sound very strange?

Comment: Tone of voice can change things around, but in text, I read “stop it” as being stern, or even angry with the man. This severity contrasts strongly with the playfulness of “We have eyes on us” which is why I find it strange.